# React native log shows objects as "[object Object]"

Tags: json, react-native, logging

I'm new to React native, I tried calling:

```
fetch('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log(`TEST RESPONSE: ${responseData}`);
    });
```

to fetch the API and log it to debug. I expected to see the details of the result just like in the tutorial but instead, I got the output like:

> > TEST RESPONSE: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

It's supposed to be somehow like this, where I can expand the data to see the array:
[image]

However, the result can be used and being populated into the list normally.

I am using

> react-native-cli: 2.0.1
>
> react-native: 0.56.0

What did I do wrong? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to print it with `console.log('TEST RESPONSE:', responseData)`